# Vs.Net C# Azure flle storage fails to add File for existing File Share

Tags: c#, azure, file, storage

VS.NET C# fails to create file on Azure File Storage for Existing File share

I'm using  **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage** lib to access Azure File Storage API. My method creates File Share and uploads file. It works when File Share is created, but skips file upload when File Share exists.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage; 
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;

public void SaveText( string fileName )
{
  string accountName = "mylogs";
  string key = @"dvjdjhsvdjfhvsjhdvfjhsvdfjhC2g==";

  var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, key), true);
  var share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("test");
  share.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
  var root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
  root.GetFileReference(fileName).UploadTextAsync("mytext").Wait(); 
}
```

First SaveText(**file1**) call works fine, Share & "**file1**" got created.
Second SaveText(**file2**) call, no errors, no "**file2**" created.
Same user, same app.

Comment: How do you call the SaveText() method? and which nuget package are you using? I'm using nuget package WindowsAzure.Storage, version 9.3.3, and a console project(not .net core), everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the nuget package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), version 9.3.3, and with a console project(not .net core), it works fine.

Sample code as blow(just use yours):

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using System;

namespace AzureFileTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.SaveText("file1"); //in the first call, file1 created and text uploads.
            p.SaveText("file2"); //in the second call, file2 created and text uploads.         

            Console.WriteLine("done now");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public void SaveText(string fileName)
        {
            string accountName = "xxxxx";
            string key = "xxxxxx";

            var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, key), true);
            var share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("test");
            share.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();

            var root = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            root.GetFileReference(fileName).UploadTextAsync("mytext").Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

Please let me know if any more issues, or any difference between the codes.

Comment: WindowsAzure.Storage, version 9.3.3, with .NET Standart 2.0 ClassLib project.

Comment: Hello @kestasj, I just created a .net standard 2.0 classlib project, and it also works fine. Not sure why it cannot work at your side. Or can you let me know how do you call this method?

Comment: My bad! That's not the code, but the MS-Azure-Explorer. I can see all my files from Azure-Portal, but from MS-Azure-Explorer only the files created with new Share. Weird! Refresh is not helping. Ok, I need to re-open Share Tab to see all updates. Thank You for the help!

Comment: @kestasj, since the code is fine, could you please help mark it as an answer? thanks. For your issue with azure explorer, you'd better raise a new issue if the issue still exists.